# How to handle a character encoding exception in Ruby 1.9.3 CSV class?

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-1.9.3

Before ruby 1.9.3 I was able to ingest rows containing characters with incorrect encoding using Ruby's CSV library:

```
require 'csv' 
CSV.open('file').each |row|
   ... #deal with wrong encoded characters here 
end
```

CSV in Ruby 1.9.3 raises exception with 'bad' rows -- `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` which I cannot figure out how to catch inside of the block. I see two solutions, both are slow:

## 1. ~8 times slower:

> ```
> open('file').each |line|
>   begin
>      CSV.parse(line)
>    rescue ArgumentError
>      line.encode!('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '?')
>      line.encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-16')
>      CSV.parse(line)
>    end
> end
> ```

## 2. ~2 times slower

fix encoding in the file before sending it to CSV.

What is a faster way to deal with rows containing 'bad' characters?

Comment: If you can, cleanse your input by reading/cleansing/writing the data as a text file, to fix it en masse. Then load it row by row as CSV. That will be a lot faster than trying to fix it on a row by row basis.

Comment: Hm, isn't it the same as #2 solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
CSV.open("file", "r:bom|utf-8").each |row|

end
```

Comment: You just saved me a lot of grief.

Comment: Why include the bom flag? I don't see this in other examples for the same problem.

Comment: The root cause is that the poster probably doesn't know what the encoding in the file is.  r:bom tells ruby to guess, which gets things encoded correctly as you read them.